# Redirecionamento interno URL amigável

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Estou criando uma página com galeria de imagens com banco de dados, e ao clicar em uma imagem, é redirecionado para a page `profile.php` com os dados da imagem, como se fosse um perfil.

Quero deixar minha URL mais bonita, atualmente está aparecendo assim:

```
localhost/meusite/profile?slug=nome-da-imagem
```

Gostaria de deixar assim:

```
localhost/meusite/nome-da-imagem
```

Vou postar a estrutura e parte do código para melhor entender, está difícil para mim achar uma solução.
A estrutura de arquivos está assim:

- MeuSite

  - css

    - style.css
  - js

    - script.js
  - pages

    - home
    - profile
  - cPanel

    - pages
    - uploads
  - .htaccess
  - config.php
  - index.php

---

no config.php:

```
define('INCLUDE_PATH', 'http://localhost/meuSite/');
define('INCLUDE_PATH_PAINEL',INCLUDE_PATH.'painel/');//usei esses 
  INCLUDE_PATH pra nao precisar configurar muito ao passar para o servidor.

define('BASE_DIR_PAINEL',__DIR__.'/painel');

//conexao banco de dados
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','meusite');
```

---

index.php:
(não vou colocar todas tags HTML para não ocupar muito espaço)

```
   <header>
  <?php 
     $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home';
        if(file_exists('pages/'.$url.'.php')){
           include('pages/'.$url.'.php');
        }else{
           echo 'essa página não existe!';
        }
   ?>

  <footer>
 </footer>
```

---

no htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Options -Indexes
```

---

na home.php:

```
<section>
//conexão do banco

<?php

//MySql::banco() = função para conectar no meu banco de dados.

$bd = MySql::Banco()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `nome_tabela`");

$bd->execute();

$imagens = $bd->fetchAll();

foreach($imagens as $key => $value){

$slug = $value['slug'];

?>


<a href="<?php echo INCLUDE_PATH; ?>profile?slug=<?php echo $slug?>"></a>

<?php }?>
```

---

na page profile.php:

```
<?php

$slug = $_GET['slug'];
if($slug == $slug){
$bd = MySql::Banco()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `nome_tabela ` WHERE slug = 
?");
$bd->execute(array($slug));
$imagens = $bd->fetchAll();
foreach ($imagens as $key => $value) {
?>


 <h1><?php echo $value['nome_img'];</h1>
 <img scr="<?php INCLUDE_PATH;?>uploads/<?php echo $value['imagem'];?>"
 <?php } ?>
```